# What happens during initialization of a bare brand new hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive

Do Operating systems handle it differently? Can you tell if a hard disk was first initialized by Windows or Linux on later abduction?

Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7_aZwQ_p4w

After plugging it in, but before partitioning and formatting.

Comment: It's pretty ugly.  It involves whipped cream, handcuffs, a cat-o-nine-tails, and a carrot.

Comment: Then you didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no permanent residue left by an operating system that first initialised a disk. That is, you can take a disk formatted by Windows, reformat it for use with Linux or Apple and there will be (if you do the full setup), nothing to leave a clue that it was Windows originally. Or not to a normal user anyway. There are forensic technique to recover data that might be able to work out that you started with a Windows loader rather than a Linux or Apple one but you need specialised equipment for that. ;)

Technically, you could put a bootloader on the raw disk. But most bootloaders are looking for their second stage to the FS in a partition to get going... so it would be an unusual state to find a bootloader without other evidence of the disk usage. And the bootloader would give you an implication of the intent. It wouldn't prevent you from creating arbitrary partitions, etc. You might not be able to *boot* them, but you could have them. :)

Temporary data - depends on whether the disk is the bootable disk of an OS. Generally, a non-bootable disk can be any file system that the OS uses. So you could have a bootable disk for Linux, and a second non-bootable disk partitioned as if for Windows with NTFS. In which case the secondary disk is only distinguishable from an NTFS secondary used on Windows because you have other inferences... what gets put on the disk would have to be the main clues.

What temporary data is there that gives a clue as to the last OS that initialised a bootable disk? Mostly the type of loader, and the file systems that have been put in the partitions. Windows tends to use NTFS. Apple uses HFS. Linux... mostly uses ext4, might have been using ext3, or reiserFS, or NTFS, or FAT32, or... a lot. Linux will be better identified by one of the boot loaders because only the strangest people run Windows and then use a different boot loader. GRUB, and LILO, etc, suggest that the most recent OS was Linux - because you mostly won't use those with Mac OS X only, and you'd only use other bootloaders with Windows if you were also running Linux, or had been intending to do so. No GRUB - then the disk is probably not used as a primary disk by Linux. With Grub and HFS - look for the other partition with a Linux FS... because it is probably a dual booted system. GRUB with NTFS and a Linux FS - dual booted to Windows and Linux. etc.

The easiest signals are that:

- the disk has no alternate bootloaders and does have NTFS - it's Windows.
- the disk has HFS only - it's Mac OS X
- the disk has GRUB or another bootloader, and ext4 - it's Linux

In ancient times, floppy disks for Macs were different media than floppy disks for PCs. It was pretty much impossible to handle a Mac floppy in a PC. It's sufficiently long ago that I can't recall exactly why.

Answer (score -5):

Revised:
Yes, different OSes place different information on the hard drive when it is partitioned and formatted. For disks under 2 TB, a Master Boot Record (MBR) is used and for disks over 2 TB, a GUID Partition Table (GPT) is used. GPT can be used on smaller disks as well. Windows installs a bootloader (from Microsoft) and many Unix ditributions uses GRUB (or GRUB2) as a bootloader. Also, GRUB is capable of more formats than the Windows bootloader.

To determine which OS initialized the hard disk, you would need to determine which system placed the bootloader on the disk. But since the bootloader can easily be replaced, all you really know is the latest OS to place the bootloader.

Comment: This is incorrect. GRUB is not a different style of partition table layout, but instead a bootloader.

Comment: You say that Linux uses GRUB (or GRUB2) instead of MBR. This is absolutely incorrect. GRUB often makes use of MBR. Additionally, ext4 most definitely can exist with MBR. The partition identifier is 0x83 in that case.

Comment: you are mistaken. See for example, https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html which states for example, "under Linux the following will install GRUB into the MBR of the first IDE disk". See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#Booting which explains how GRUB and the MBR work together.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Linux supports MBR and GPT.  Both `GRUB` and `Grub 2` are bootloaders.  You wonder the reason you recieve downvotes, this is the reason, the answer is **incorrect**.  Windows bootloader is also installed into the MBR if you want to get technical

Comment: You keep saying that.  Your statement is specific you said it uses Grub instead of MBR which isn't the case.

Comment: The other item of note: so many people commented that I was wrong, but they never posted their own answer: why is that?

Comment: BTW, I remember a DOS version (DrDOS, I believe) having a program called MBR.EXE which fixed a corrupted MBR.